# daily post to application users wall

Tags: facebook

i want to post daily note to facebook  user profile which using my facebook application via it's own. how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't provide what language or what you've tried so far, these are quick tips to get you started:

1. Ask for the [`publish_stream` permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)
2. Then using your SDK or the technology you are using ([source](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/note/)):

   ```
   curl -F 'access_token=...' \
        -F 'subject=This is a note' \
        -F 'message=Test note.' \
        https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/notes
   ```
3. No need for the `access_token` parameter.

Comment: thanks ifaour im using PHP and need to post application user's wall without promt ant publish message daily. how can i do it?